# Desktop does not open

Tags: desktop-environments

I unfortunately moved the desktop folder to another place. Now - as you can see - in the image "Desktop/schreibtisch" is not anynore in the list under "Rechner". When starting therefore I do not get the desktop but the content of "gustav" and on this a "Desktop"-Folder. What do I have to do that the computer starts again with the Desktop?
Thx for help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the hidden configuration file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` in your home directory and open it with a text file editor. (The folder that contains the file, `.config`, is a hidden folder. Turn "Show hidden folders" on in your file manager to see that folder).

Change the line for the Desktop folder so it reads like

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

for English versions, or the actual name of your desktop folder if the name is localized.

Comment: That would be `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Schreibtisch"` in German.

Comment: @Jos Very right - I added a note to that respect, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Dear Jos, dear Vanadium,
thank you so much. Worked perfectly.
That is one of the reason I like/love Linux: Generally, one gets immediate help from the community. I would regard myself as a semi-experienced user, but I could not have handled this stupid mistake of mine without your help.
Buelent

Comment: @Buelent, please be sure to mark this thread as answered so that those who helped get the proper attribution, and this thread is closed out appropriately. Thanks